# Passed css parameter is not used in component

Tags: html, svelte

I want to pass css parameters down to a component, after reading this page:
https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0000-style-properties.md

Somehow I don't get it.

The passed css never occurs, instead the default fallback color is shown:

```
<!-- Heroitem.svelte -->
<style>
.blabla{
    background-image: var(--background-image, linear-gradient(150deg,#ffffff,#ab12b94f));
}
</style>
```

What have I tried? First, I define the content of the items:

```
<!-- Hero.svelte -->    
let items = [
    title: "MyApp",
    css: {
        backgroundimage: 'linear-gradient(150deg,#cecece,#7e7e7e);'
    }
]
```

I am doing this for first test:

```
<!-- Hero.svelte -->
{#each items as item, i (item.title)}
<Heroitem title={item.title} 
          --background-image='linear-gradient(150deg,#cecece,#7e7e7e);'
/>
{/each}
```

And ultimately want to do this:

```
<Heroitem title={item.title} 
    --background-image={item.css.backgroundimage}
/>
```

I am using svelte-3.32.3

UPDATE

It seems like for passing to components, you have to use normal properties.

```
<!-- Heroitem.svelte -->
<script>
    ...
    export let css_backgroundimage
</script>

<div class="test" style="--background-image:{css_backgroundimage}">...</div>

<style>
    .test{
        background-image: var(--background-image}
    }
</style>


<!-- Hero.svelte -->
<Heroitem css_backgroundimage={item.css.backgroundimage} />
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: In your first code example you are passing multiple arguments to var function which is incorrect, have you noticed that ?

Comment: Yes. The second part is the default fallback. This is the color that I've seen displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** as of Svelte 3.38.0, this feature has been implemented.

You can now pass CSS custom properties directly without exposing a separate prop:

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<Heroitem title={item.title} 
    --background-image={item.css.backgroundimage}
/>

<!-- Heroitem.svelte -->
<style>
    .blabla {
        background-image: var(--background-image, linear-gradient(150deg,#ffffff,#ab12b94f));
    }
</style>
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**
The document you linked is an RFC and is that feature is not yet implemented in Svelte. See this [issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5628) to track the feature's progress.

In the meantime, you can use the workaround you described by passing it as a prop and setting it as a CSS variable in the component.

```
<!-- Heroitem.svelte -->
<script>
    ...
    export let css_backgroundimage
</script>

<div class="test" style="--background-image:{css_backgroundimage}">...</div>

<style>
    .test {
        background-image: var(--background-image}
    }
</style>


<!-- Hero.svelte -->
<Heroitem css_backgroundimage={item.css.backgroundimage} />
```

Alternatively, you could set the variable in a wrapper element outside the component and it should work the same.

```
<!-- Heroitem.svelte -->
<div class="test">...</div>

<style>
    .test {
        background-image: var(--background-image}
    }
</style>


<!-- Hero.svelte -->
<div style="--background-image: {item.css.backgroundimage}">
    <Heroitem />
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I was looking if there was a commit already, and I found one (not the right one obviously). Regarding the link https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/pull/13 it seemed as if it was working. Thanks for the issue link :)

Comment: As of version 3.38, the feature has been implemented! I've updated my answer accordingly.